# Default UITableView Cell automatic height

Tags: swift, uitableview

i have a UITableViewController, with a cell of the style uitableviewcellstylesubtitle, where the subtitle-label has numberoflines=0

and if i do

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0
```

the cells dont do automatic height, can it really be true - that you can't use that on the default styled cells?

EDIT:

Simple population

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    let thisHelpArticle = helpObjects[indexPath.section]

    cell.textLabel!.text = thisHelpArticle.helpHeadline
    cell.detailTextLabel!.text = thisHelpArticle.helpDescription

    return cell
}
```

Comment: We need more information. Please show us how you populate cells. Plus, are you using autolayout?

Comment: As stated, its just a uitableviewcontroller with a default cell with the Subtitle style, so you can't add autolayout, will add population above

Comment: Can you call `cell.layoutIfNeeded()` right before returning the cell?

Comment: Doesn't change height

Comment: @magnuskahr You don't seem to create any cell.

Comment: @BhavukJain what do you mean? The cells sure show up when i run the app, they just dont resize to fit the text and stays at 44pt

Comment: @magnuskahr cell = UITableViewCell(style: .Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "Cell"). Put this if cell is nil.

Comment: @BhavukJain It says "Value of type 'UITableViewCell' can never be nil, comparison isn't allowed"

Comment: @magnuskahr change it to var cell.

Comment: Please check my updated below answer. It has nothing to do with var or let. It should stay as let.

Answer (score 6):

UPDATE!!!
In order for the default cell subtitle to autoresize the cell, you MUST set both label's number of lines to 0. Otherwise it doesn't work. Weird.

```
cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
cell.detailTextLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
```

You can auto resize default sytled cells. In its simplest form I have the following code. Which is auto resizing the default styled subtitle cell.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        let thisHelpArticle = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vel porttitor blandit, aliquam tristique vestibulum, enim vel eros fames id, in gravida vestibulum gravida tempor, et vel libero sed mauris. Suspendisse ut placerat viverra dictum, ante ante vel ut vestibulum sollicitudin phasellus. Dictumst adipiscing adipiscing nisl, fusce ut. Ante wisi pellentesque, et aliquam rhoncus eget convallis quam voluptate, ut nec quis, sodales ullamcorper elementum pellentesque sagittis vitae, dolor justo fermentum amet risus. Eu placerat ultricies. Ipsum sodales, massa elit, in neque, sed penatibus gravida, cursus eget. Ut tincidunt at eu, wisi dis vel penatibus eget, volutpat ligula vel tortor morbi feugiat, dui et eiusmod dis sociis. Iaculis lorem molestie laoreet sit, orci commodo, fusce vestibulum sapien, quisque egestas maecenas sed rem in nisl."

        cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
        cell.detailTextLabel?.numberOfLines = 0

        cell.textLabel!.text = thisHelpArticle
        cell.detailTextLabel!.text = thisHelpArticle

        return cell
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate {

}
```

Comment: I figured out the same just as you wrote it, the cell becomes bigger but still cuts of some text as i can see

Comment: Indeed it does. I guess you need to subclass it. Weird though. Upvote for enlighting question.